# Error in tables numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, captions

i have an error in the numbering of the tables. some of the number are missing and don't know what is the problem. the following picture illustrate the problem. please i need your help!
[image]

Comment: do you have longtables between the tables?

Comment: latex will not drop the numbering for no reason, what is different about the markup of the table that should have been 3.11

Comment: Hello Ulrike, yes i have a longtable without caption because i don't need it

Comment: in that case (which you should have put in the question) put `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` after the longtable

Comment: thank you David, it worksss!

Comment: Or use [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular), a drop-in replacement for longtable.